# how to get callback status in twilio

Tags: twilio

How to callback status in twilio for example in php.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "---------------";
$token = "-----------------;
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$call = $client->calls->create(
    $to, $from,
    array(
        "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",//this line complete
        "method" => "GET",
        "statusCallbackMethod" => "POST",
        "statusCallback" => "https://www.myapp.com/events", //in this line no idea
        "statusCallbackEvent" => array(
            "initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed"
        )
    )
);

echo $call->sid;
```

In this example how to get event after call

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct for registering call status notifications from Twilio. For every event you specified in your `statusCallbackEvent` array, Twilio will make an asynchronous HTTP request to the URL specified in the `statusCallback` parameter. See [this](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132267-Tracking-the-call-status-of-an-outbound-call) article for more details.

So now you will need a service at this URL: https://www.myapp.com/events, listening for notification sent by Twilio. In your case these will be POST requests, given the method you specified in `statusCallbackMethod` parameter. The parameter you need to tell which event is being notified is `CallStatus`. See [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#synchronous-request-parameters) documentation for more info.

We're not using PHP, but if you want to do a quick test, just create a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/functions) and paste the following code in there to see your event notifications:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  let response = { get_started: true };

  console.log(`Call status notified was '${event.CallStatus}'.`);

  callback(null, response);
};
```